# Dropbox Datastore - recordsChanged listeners for individual tables?

Tags: javascript, dropbox, dropbox-api, datastore

Dropbox datastore api - javascript

Is there a way to set up different listeners for each table?

Something like this:

```
favoritesTable = datastore.getTable('favorites');
trackTable = datastore.getTable('track');
favoritesTable.recordsChanged.addListener(syncFavorites);
trackTable.recordsChanged.addListener(syncTrack);
```

Or is there a way to specify which table has changed?

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for using the datastore-api tag!

The API does not let you do this.  This is somewhat intentional, because we want to emphasize that sync() (whether explicit, as for Android/iOS, or implicit, as for JS) always updates the whole datastore.  (You can think of it as a transaction, actually.)

If you're only interested in a specific table, it's easy enough to introduce a helper function in your app that calls `update.affectedRecordsForTable('favorites')` and only calls the "real" callback if the result is non-empty.  Or you could have a function that you call for each record -- then you wouldn't even need the "if", just a loop over the results.